# Please help, Can't install Jinitiator 1.3.1.17 on Window 7

Tags: oracle, installation, jinitiator

I've been trying to install "Jinitiator 1.3.1.17" on Window7 for 2 days, but it doesn't work.

I have jinit.exe on my pc and i run this as administrator.
After the onscreen prompt appeared, it showed only about 3 sec and then it disappeared.

I've waited.... but nothing happens.
So i look at the Process in TaskManager to check whether the program still runing or not. And i found "jinit.exe *32" and "setup.exe *32" on the screen.

I don't know what to do, I tried all my best.

Anyone can help me please

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to oracle note 1234626.1, which you'll need an oracle support license to view, jinitiator is not compatible or certified on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Visual Effects to Adjust for Best Performance

System Properties -> Advanced -> Performance - > Settings

Select Adjust for Best Performance.